# Dask Distributed: How to delete uploaded files from the cluster

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

I wanted to know if there's a function in `dask.distributed` that removes the files uploaded to the cluster using the [`client.upload_file()`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.upload_file)?

Basically, the opposite of the `upload_file()` function.
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function to do this directly as of today. But as a work-around, you can use `client.run` with `os.remove`:

```
client.run(lambda dask_worker: os.remove(os.path.join(dask_worker.local_directory, "file.py")))
```

where `file.py` can be replaced by the name of the file that you uploaded.

Note that the input argument to `client.run` must be `dask_worker`, relevant docs here: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.run